# Motion layout add constraint attribute to transition

Tags: android-motionlayout

I have a simple motion layout that changes from one layout to another.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetStart="@layout/activity_new"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@layout/activity_new_ii"
        motion:duration="1000">
    </Transition>

</MotionScene>
```

Here I also want to animate a layouts aplha which is a direct child of the motionlayout. The docs show constraint attributes applied to views individually. like in this [atricle](https://medium.com/google-developers/introduction-to-motionlayout-part-ii-a31acc084f59). How does one add the attribute to the transition between the layouts.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use motion layout to animate between different layouts (i.e. layouts of different activities). Motion layout only animates the views inside of it. 
On the other hand, you could include both layouts that you want to transition inside of the motion layout and start from there...