# Motion Layout reset on navigating between activities

Tags: android-motionlayout

I am using motion layout in my mainactivity. It is working proplerly. However when I move to other activities and navigate back to my mainactivity sometimes the activity is reset and the layout is in its starting state.How do I keep this from happening ? Apart from this 
 I also have another question about motion layout which I have asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53993841/motion-layout-add-constraint-attribute-to-transition)

Answer (score 10):

What I did was adding a field, a boolean field to be specific and use the life cycle to handle it.

```
    private var hasMotionScrolled = false

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (hasMotionScrolled) motionLayout.progress = MOTION_TRANSITION_COMPLETED
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        hasMotionScrolled = motionLayout.progress > MOTION_TRANSITION_INITIAL
    }


    companion object {
        private const val MOTION_TRANSITION_COMPLETED = 1F
        private const val MOTION_TRANSITION_INITIAL = 0F
    }
```

So in my case, motion layout is doing an animation related to scrolling. If this is not your case maybe you can use directly the `motionLayout.progress`. My problem with using the `progress` directly was that intermediate states would make other elements not visible when navigating back, that is why implemented an all or nothing boolean flag.

I don't see this as a clean solution, a flag is always something that means something else could have been better, if you can find something official, please let me know in the comments.

Comment: Only working solution in combination with NavigationComponents. Small improvement: don't forget to save the variable in `onSaveInstanceState`

Answer (score 3):

You have to save/restore the progress of your MotionLayout:

```
    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.putFloat("progress", motionLayout.progress)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        if (savedInstanceState != null)
            motionLayout.progress = savedInstanceState.getFloat("progress", 0f)
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it with `Fragment`

Create an instance variable on your `Fragment` class:

```
var motionProgress = 0f // 0f being initial state
```

On your `onViewCreated` function, give the current value to the layout:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    binding.motionLayout.progress = motionProgress
}
```

Finally, when navigating away from the `Fragment`, update the value of `motionProgress` on function `onPause`:

```
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()

    motionProgress = binding.motionLayout.progress
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a transition listener to the motion layout & save a flag when the transition is completed. Afterwards, when the activity gets recreated, you can read that flag and use smth like:

`motionLayout.setState(R.id.end, ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT, ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT)`

Where R.id.end is the id from constraintSetEnd property.

Comment: I did not unserstand

Answer (score 0):

```
class ExtMotionLayout : MotionLayout {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(): Parcelable? {
        return SavedState(progress, super.onSaveInstanceState())
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(state: Parcelable?) {
        if (state is SavedState) {
            progress = state.progress
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(state.superState)
        } else super.onRestoreInstanceState(state)
    }

    class SavedState : BaseSavedState {
        val progress: Float

        constructor(progress: Float, source: Parcelable?) : super(source) {
            this.progress = progress
        }

        constructor(superState: Parcel) : super(superState) {
            progress = superState.readFloat()
        }

        override fun writeToParcel(out: Parcel, flags: Int) {
            super.writeToParcel(out, flags)
            out.writeFloat(progress)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is working but after process death application crash

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomMotionLayout(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : MotionLayout(context, attrs) {
    init {
        isSaveEnabled = true
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(): Parcelable {
        return SavedState(progress, super.onSaveInstanceState())
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(state: Parcelable?) {
        if (state is SavedState) {
            progress = state.progress
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(state.superState)
        } else super.onRestoreInstanceState(state)
    }

    class SavedState(val progress: Float, source: Parcelable?) : BaseSavedState(source) {

        override fun writeToParcel(out: Parcel, flags: Int) {
            super.writeToParcel(out, flags)
            out.writeFloat(progress)
        }
    }
}
```

Use `CustomMotionLayout` instead of default MotionLayout
Just keep in mind to provide id to your motion layout