# Snackbar appears in different styles with same code: Normal in one and a floating snackbar. in another activity

Tags: android-snackbar

I am showing a snackbar in two different activities. The code for the snackbar is

```
  Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Do you want to log out ?", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        View view = snackbar.getView();
        TextView textView = view.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        snackbar.setAction("Log out", v1 -> {
            snackbar.setText("Please wait");
            //call log out api
        });
        snackbar.show();
```

When I call it from my first activity it looks like this.
https://ibb.co/56QfCW8

When I call it from my secong activity it looks like this.
https://ibb.co/0MZ8LcQ

The only difference is the the first activity has framelayout as the rootlayout and the second one has a motion layout.
The styles are the same in both the activities.

First activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black">
    <com.joooonho.SelectableRoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/loginn"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:sriv_border_color="@color/black"
        app:sriv_border_width="2dip"
        app:sriv_left_bottom_corner_radius="0dip"
        app:sriv_left_top_corner_radius="16dip"
        app:sriv_right_bottom_corner_radius="0dip"
        app:sriv_right_top_corner_radius="16dip" />
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraint"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:text="@string/full_name"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />


            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_email"
                style="@style/TextInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:hint="username"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/tie_email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_name"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_password"
                style="@style/TextInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:hint="password"
                app:passwordToggleTint="@color/white"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/til_email"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/til_email"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/til_email"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/tie_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_key"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_key"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


            <br.com.simplepass.loading_button_lib.customViews.CircularProgressButton
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_default"
                android:onClick="login"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="Login"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:finalCornerAngle="50dp"
                app:initialCornerAngle="50dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/til_password"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/til_password"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/til_password"
                app:spinning_bar_color="#fff"
                app:spinning_bar_padding="6dp"
                app:spinning_bar_width="4dp" />


            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>


</FrameLayout>
```

Second activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.motion.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/motionLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/scene_01"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/materialCardView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="2.5"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4">

        <android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/materialCardView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            app:cardElevation="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:strokeColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:strokeWidth="2dp">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/num"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:text="Phone Number"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:text=":"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/num"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/num"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/num"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:text="Email ID"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/num"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/num"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/num" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=":"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView4"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView5" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:text="Batch"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView5"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=":"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView6"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView6"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView7" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:text="90000000000"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView10"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:text="username@gmail.com"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView6"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView6" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:text="Kolkata"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView8"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView>

        <android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            style="@style/Button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="74dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="Payment Status"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button2" />

        <android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="@style/Button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="74dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="Admission Details"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/materialCardView" />

        <android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="@style/Button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="74dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Rules and Regulation"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />

        <android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            style="@style/Button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="74dp"
            android:text="Leave"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button3" />

        <android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            style="@style/Button"
            android:layout_width="184dp"
            android:layout_height="74dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
            android:text="Attendance"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3" />


        <android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:text="Log out"
            app:icon="@drawable/exit"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/space3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/materialCardView" />

        <Space
            android:id="@+id/space3"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/materialCardView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/materialCardView"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.882"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button7"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/materialCardView"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.227" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/materialCardView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/loginn" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Firstname Lastname"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/materialCardView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/loginn"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
        app:civ_border_width="1dp"
        app:civ_shadow="true"
        app:civ_shadow_color="#000000"
        app:civ_shadow_radius="0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/space"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/space"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/space"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
</android.support.constraint.motion.MotionLayout>
```

Although the second **floating snackbar** looks better I cannot reproduce it on any other activities. I have tried the same code on a different motion layout and the snackbar looks normal.

Comment: check whether you are not using different styles for both activities.

Comment: Yeah sorry silly mistake. I was using a bridge theme

Comment: hey if you are familiar with motion layout please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54002303/motion-layout-reset-on-navigating-between-activities/54019758#54019758